# How to make Beam queries?

Tags: haskell, haskell-beam

I just started off with Haskell and recently Beam. I went through the documentation somehow but couldn't grasp it very well.

How does one make simple queries?

I can see in the documentation that

functions like `filter_` take a lambda function as input parameter.

From documentation

```
filter_ (\s -> addressCity (customerAddress s) ==. val_ (Just "Berlin")) $
all_ (customer chinookDb)
```

what is `s`? what values (and type) does the beam library provide to the lambda function which we provide? `addressCity (customerAddress s)` is the entirety a column? I understand that `customer` is the table and `chinookDb` is the DB.

I am more interested in making a sum query. An equivalent of just

`SELECT SUM(colname) FROM TABLE;`

However the documentation gives off only a somewhat complicated query as an example.

```
    aggregate_ (\(genre, track) ->
              ( group_ genre
              , as_ @Int $ countOver_ distinctInGroup_ (trackUnitPrice track)
              , fromMaybe_ 0 (sumOver_ allInGroupExplicitly_ (fromMaybe_ 0 (trackMilliseconds track))) `div_` 1000)) $ do
  g <- all_ (genre chinookDb)
  t <- genreTracks g
  pure (g, t)
```

I can tell that `sum_` is similar to `count_` but then again what lambda function must be provided to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

If you question about what lambda function *can* take as input it becomes clear.

So this expression:

`aggregate_ (\x -> sum_ (hello x))` is actually `aggregate_ (\col -> sum_ (colT col))`

where `colT` is the the column you defined while defined the Beam Table. The existence of `colT` in the lambda function will be enough for Beam to fetch the corresponding column from the table and pass that value to the function.